# Setting up SRos2 Security Keystore

Tags: ros2

I am new to ROS2 and would like some help setting up a security keystore correctly for SROS2 use. I am using nodes very similar to the talker/listener nodes described in this demo [SROS2 Demo](https://docs.ros.org/en/rolling/Tutorials/Advanced/Security/Introducing-ros2-security.html) for testing if my nodes can communicate with each other. My issue is instead of using the ros2 security cli commands to set up the keystore, my project requires me to set all this up manually. However, when I set everything up, I see the error below. Can somebody help me understand the cause of this? I am mainly using ROS Foxy with its default RMW implementation, but I have also tested this on Rolling.

```
[INFO] [1695145261.061412775] [rcl]: Found security directory: /home/calvin/secureDDS/robot_keys/enclaves/demo/publisher
2023-09-19 13:41:01.065 [RTPS_PARTICIPANT Error] Cannot create participant due to security initialization error -> Function createParticipant
2023-09-19 13:41:01.066 [PARTICIPANT Error] Problem creating RTPSParticipant -> Function createParticipant

>>> [rcutils|error_handling.c:108] rcutils_set_error_state()
This error state is being overwritten:

  'create_node() could not create participant, at /tmp/binarydeb/ros-foxy-rmw-fastrtps-shared-cpp-1.3.1/src/participant.cpp:116, at /tmp/binarydeb/ros-foxy-rcl-1.1.14/src/rcl/node.c:276'

with this new error message:

  'rcl node's rmw handle is invalid, at /tmp/binarydeb/ros-foxy-rcl-1.1.14/src/rcl/node.c:428'

rcutils_reset_error() should be called after error handling to avoid this.
<<<
[ERROR] [1695145261.066157866] [rcl]: Failed to fini publisher for node: 1
terminate called after throwing an instance of 'rclcpp::exceptions::RCLError'
  what():  failed to initialize rcl node: rcl node's rmw handle is invalid, at /tmp/binarydeb/ros-foxy-rcl-1.1.14/src/rcl/node.c:428
```

### BACKGROUND

I create a testing keystore and the commands below are what I use to set it up. I then compare this test keystore against a ros2 generated one. My steps are as follows.

I set up the directories in a way similar to the demo specified earlier.

[image: Directory Structure]

Since the governance.xml and permissions.xml files will be identical to what im trying to test, I copy those over from the Ros generated Keystore to my keystore. I then create the certificate and key with these commands.

```
openssl ecparam -name prime256v1 -genkey -noout -out ca.key.pem
openssl req -new -nodes -out ca.crt -key ca.key.pem -config <config file>
openssl ca -out ca.cert.pem -keyfile ca.key.pem -selfsign -config <config file> -in ca.crt
```

and then I create the nodes certificate and private key.

```
openssl ecparam -name prime256v1 -genkey -noout -out key.pem
openssl req -new -nodes -out cert.crt -key key.pem -sha256 -days 365 *Specifying the common name as the enclave*
openssl x509 -req -in cert.crt -days 365 -CA ca.cert.pem -CAkey ca.key.pem -CAcreateserial -out cert.pem -sha256
```

After that I create symbolic links of ca.cert.pem (identity_ca.cert.pem, permissions_ca.cert.pem) and ca.key.pem (identity_ca.key.pem, permissions_ca.key.pem), and sign the governance and permissions xml files like so.

```
openssl smime -sign -in permissions.xml -inkey ca.key.pem -signer ca.cert.pem -out permissions.p7s
openssl smime -sign -in governance.xml -inkey ca.key.pem -signer ca.cert.pem -out governance.p7s
```

*I have also tried signing the files with "**permissions_ca**" key and cert but since they are symbolic links, I figured that wouldn't change the outcome.*

Once I have all the files in place my directories look like this, which directly mimics what is seen if you were to use the ros2 security cli commands **ros2 security create_keystore robot_keys/** and **ros2 security create_key robot_keys /demo/publisher** to set everything up.

```
robot_keys/
├── enclaves
│   ├── demo
│   │   └── publisher
│   │       ├── cert.pem
│   │       ├── governance.p7s -> ../../governance.p7s
│   │       ├── identity_ca.cert.pem -> ../../../public/identity_ca.cert.pem
│   │       ├── key.pem
│   │       ├── permissions_ca.cert.pem -> ../../../public/permissions_ca.cert.pem
│   │       ├── permissions.p7s
│   │       └── permissions.xml
│   ├── governance.p7s
│   └── governance.xml
├── private
│   ├── ca.key.pem
│   ├── identity_ca.key.pem -> ca.key.pem
│   └── permissions_ca.key.pem -> ca.key.pem
└── public
    ├── ca.cert.pem
    ├── identity_ca.cert.pem -> ca.cert.pem
    └── permissions_ca.cert.pem -> ca.cert.pem
```

I set the environment variables like so

```
export ROS_SECURITY_KEYSTORE="/home/calvin/secureDDS/robot_keys"
export ROS_SECURITY_ENCLAVE_OVERRIDE="/demo/publisher"
export ROS_SECURITY_ENABLE=true
export ROS_SECURITY_STRATEGY="Enforce"
```

and run my publishing node right after

`ros2 run minimal_publisher minimal_publisher`

Then I see the error described earlier. I have also tried copying over the ca.cert.pem and ca.key.pem to the testing keystore and using those to sign everything which results in no success and the same error.

If it will help, this is the openssl config file I am using.

#### certificate.cnf

```
################ Req Section ################
# This is used by the `openssl req` command
# to create a certificate request

[ req ]

# Don't prompt for the DN, use configured values instead
# This saves having to type in your DN each time.

prompt             = no
string_mask        = default
distinguished_name = req_dn

# The size of the keys in bits:
default_bits       = 2048

# The extensions added when generating a CSR
#req_extensions     = req_ext

[ req_dn ]

commonName              = secmation

[ req_ext ]

# Extensions added to the request

################ CA Section ################
# This is used with the 'openssl ca' command
# to sign a request

[ ca ]

default_ca = CA

[ CA ]

# Where OpenSSL stores information

dir             = .                             # Where everything is kept
certs           = $dir                          # Where the issued certs are kept
crldir          = $dir                          # Where the issued crl are kept

new_certs_dir   = $certs
database        = $dir/index 
serial          = $dir/serial.txt

# How OpenSSL will display certificate after signing
name_opt    = ca_default
cert_opt    = ca_default

# How long the CA certificate is valid for
default_days = 3650
# default_startdate  = 180517000000Z
# default_enddate    = 181231235959Z

# The message digest for self-signing the certificate
# sha1 or sha256 for best compatability, although most
# OpenSSL digest algorithm can be used.
# md4,md5,mdc2,rmd160,sha1,sha256
default_md = sha256

# Subjects don't have to be unique in this CA's database
unique_subject    = no
# What to do with CSR extensions
copy_extensions    = copy

# Rules on mandatory or optional DN components
policy      = simple_policy

# Extensions added while singing with the `openssl ca` command
x509_extensions = x509_ext

[ simple_policy ]
countryName             = optional
stateOrProvinceName     = optional
localityName            = optional
organizationName        = optional
organizationalUnitName  = optional
commonName              = optional
domainComponent         = optional
emailAddress            = optional
name                    = optional
surname                 = optional
givenName               = optional
dnQualifier             = optional

[ x509_ext ]

# These extensions are for a CA certificate

subjectKeyIdentifier    = hash

#basicConstraints            = critical, CA:TRUE
basicConstraints          = critical, CA:TRUE, pathlen:1

#keyUsage = critical, keyCertSign, cRLSign
```

Everything works correctly with no errors when using the Ros generated keystore, so I'm not sure what is happening. If anyone has any ideas or can point me in the right direction, that would be greatly appreciated.

Thank you